# program/flash tool for PSoc controllers in Ubuntu

Tags: package-management, ide, alternative

Does Linux have any cypress PSoc creator IDE alternative package or IDE to flash code on PSoc5 series controllers

Answer (score 0):

For now, I'll be using openOCD to flash programs that have already been precompiled in the PSoC Creator 4.4 IDE from windows.